# How to close multiple tabs in safari iOS 8

Tags: iphone, safari, tabs, ios

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 8, and after some minuts I ran into a problem.. 10+ open tabs in safari and I want to close them all at once. On iOS 7 I used to press the "private browse mode" and it would ask "Want to close all tabs?" Now it just goes into private browsing mode, without asking.

So is it possible to close all tabs at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Safari iOS 10 you can close all tabs by holding down the tab button

https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-close-all-safari-tabs-at-once-in-ios-10/

Comment: I just realized this feature yesterday. Anyways hope that others have been helped by your post meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

The only (very slow and clumsy) solution at the moment is to clear your Safari browsing history via the settings. At the moment there is no other way to close all tabs at once.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. Its not the solutions I was looking for, but its a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing I've found is to use multiple fingers to push as many x's on the corners of the windows as I can simultaneously. This still isn't as handy as the close all button was.

Answer (score 1):

You can swipe tabs to left. Not all at once, but still quicker

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Mac and have iCloud configured you can open Safari on your Mac and choose "View" -> "Show All Tabs". Now you'll see all open tabs on your iPhone and can quickly click on the "x" to close a tab on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the icon at top right of screen (when on Safari)it is like one oblong on top of another tap it and the screen will shrink, you will then see the close cross on top left hand corner,tap this cross,and bingo job done.

Comment: The OP is aware of this method as explained in the question but is asking how to close **all** the tabs quicker.

Comment: Yes, I need a way to close all at once! As it was possible in iOS7.